# How to keep a C++ object inside Java code? Possible?

Tags: java, c++, android, java-native-interface

First I've got a legacy C++ library, and I'm migrating my app to Android with new UI.

During runtime, there might be multiple C++ objects created and destroyed dynamically. I built a set of JNI native methods to call into library to get that. But where should I keep those C++ objects? I have to keep track of them and free them if they're unnecessary.

So far I only knew Java can't reference to a C++ object. Is it possible to make a Java wrapper class which include a reference to C++ object?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You can store a pointer to your C++ object in a simple java int. That's exactly how [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) does that.

Comment: That worked. thx. But do I have to keep it as a long? Is it possible to save it in more object-like way?

Comment: Well, you could wrap your C++ classes into Java classes, in which Java methods wrap the native methods. Upon invokation of these native methods, you pass the native pointer (int) along with other parameters. On C++ side this pointer is casted to your actual C++ class pointer, and then the method of this class is invoked. You shoud really check out [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/), it can generate all these wrappers for you automatically.

Comment: fifth, see my answer below, use JavaCPP

Comment: Careful, a native pointer these days likely can't fit in a java int, unless you have a legacy 32-bit platform.  But a long probably works, as long as you never perform operations which could misinterpret the sign bit.

Answer (score -1):

[JavaCPP](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp) takes care of this detail by saving it into a wrapping peer `Pointer` object.